# ViewHolder pattern with custom views duplicates the listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    if ( convertView == null ) 
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        View custView = new CustomView(false,  this.getItem(position), mContext, position).getView();
        holder.customView = custView;
        custView.setTag( holder );
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        custView = holder.customView;
    }
    return custView ;   
}



private static class ViewHolder 
{
    View customView;
}
```

This is part of CustomView :

```
    public View getView() {
        return mDataViewRoot;
    }

    public CustomView(boolean cameFromA, CustomDataClass customDataObject, Context ctx, int position) {
        super();
        this.cameFromA= cameFromA;
        this.customDataObject= customDataObject;
        this.mContext = ctx;
        this.mPosition = position;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        mDataViewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_root, null);
        mViewsHolder = (LinearLayout) mDataViewRoot.findViewById(R.id.data_holder);
        determineState(source);
        prepareView();
        handleCornerArea();
    }
```

I wanted to implement a view holder for performance (and better design) reasons.
However ,it ends up messing up my list, duplicating views ..

Comment: If you want to use this pattern for performance reasons, I recommend using [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

Comment: well I already have multiple list views in my project, and it's a huge project. Replacing all of them now is not an option unfortunately.
Is there a way to solve the issue with the old and good listview ?

Comment: do not pass `this.getItem(position)` and `position` to constructor ... instead make a method called fx: `bind(...)` with those two things as params and call it right before return statment in `getView`... if there is only one view there is no need for ViewHolder pattern  the `convertView` will always be null or your `CustomView`

Comment: I have a big list of CustomViews. Also , on a button click I add another list right below the existing one.

Comment: wait the minute `CustomView` is not derived from `View` and has method `getView` ... FSM save us !! ... seems like a serious design problem ... rewrite the code

Comment: Especially if it is a huge projext, I recommend it using the `RecyclerView`, since it is made for huge datasets. Nontheless, would you mind posting your `CustomView.class`? Also, look [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder) for a corrext implementation of the `ViewHolder` pattern.

Comment: It is exactly what you are doing: when the `convertView` is not null (after first time) it is reused for next views, when `getView()` is called

Comment: @Amy ... RecyclerView is not for huge datasets ads it doesnt support Cursor data ...

Comment: < A flexible view for providing a limited window into a large data set.> - [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Comment: ListView does the same ... as it using recycle pattern ... only CursorAdapter with AbstractWindowedCursor can work with really huge datasets ...

Comment: I've added the CustomView in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are setting your views data in CustomView. Don't do it like that, you need to set the views data in that adapter's getView method.

Here is the **correct** way to use view holder pattern:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    if ( convertView == null ) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        // I don't know what you are doing with the boolean value, item or position...
        convertView = new CustomView(false,  this.getItem(position), mContext, position).getView();
        holder.mCustomViewsTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customTextView);
        convertView.setTag( holder );
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mCustomViewsTextView.setText = "Item position: " + position;

    return convertView;   
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView mCustomViewsTextView;
    // Other views that are in your CustomView
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT 1:** 
If you don't want to do it that way, you must add setters to your CustomView and call those from getView method. What I am trying to say that you need to update the CustomView's data **in getView method**, if you don't, well you got the results what happens then...

**EDIT 2:** 
There is no point in your view holder pattern, you could just do it like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomView customView = (CustomView) convertView;
    if (customView == null ) {
        customView = new CustomView(false,  this.getItem(position), mContext, position).getView();
    }

    // You need to add these setters to your CustomView
    customView.setCustomDataObject(this.getItem(position));
    customView.setPosition(position);
    customView.setCameFromA(false);

    return customView;   
}
```

Comment: Wish it was that easy to do it like this. There's a lot of logic in the CustomView that determines how it should look.
I can't just use something like `"mCustomsViewTextView = "test"` and so forth..

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work.. items aren't showing right

Comment: if (customView == null ) {
        customView = new CustomView(false,  this.getItem(position), mContext, position).getView();
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107120/discussion-between-bvtp-and-vilpe89).